# Unable to show alert message in express on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I am using jQuery for button click event and trying to show alert in ejs file but alert message is not showing below is my code:

**register.ejs**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title><%= title %></title>

<style>
  
    h1 {
     text-align: center;
     margin-top:50px; 
     }
     
     .form{
       margin-top:50px;
       margin-left:30%;
       margin-right:30%;
     }

     input{
       margin-top:10px;
     }
     
     button{
        margin-top:20px;
     }

</style>

</head>
<body class="container">

<h1><%= title %></h1>

<div class="form">

    <form>

    <input name="nam" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" aria-label="default input example">
    <input name="mail" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" aria-label="default input example">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button> 
    
    </form>

</div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     
     $('.btn').click(function(){
           alert('Hello');

     });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Someone let me know what's wrong in above code.

Comment: The class selector .btn has to be in quotes... either a pair of single or double quotes

Comment: I tried it but its not  working

Comment: I got an issue actually I forgot to add JQuery library after adding it its working fine.

Comment: I always tend to miss this one: by default, a `button` will submit the form which prevents your code from running. Please add `type="button"` to your button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not implemented the JQuery library into your code. Here is the code to implement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title><%= title %></title>

    <style>
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }

      .form {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-right: 30%;
      }

      input {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      button {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <h1><%= title %></h1>

    <div class="form">
      <form>
        <input
          name="nam"
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          aria-label="default input example"
        />
        <input
          name="mail"
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
          aria-label="default input example"
        />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".btn").click(function () {
        alert("Hello");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I missed JQuery library,Thanks!